# C++ ошибка glut.h

Tags: glut, c++, opengl

Для работы в одном учебнике требовалась библиотека `glut.h`, я нашел в интернете файл `glut.h`, запихнул его в `MinGW/includes/GL` и подключил его

```
 #include  <GL\glut.h>
```

Вроде и библиотеку компилятор видит и функции которые я вызываю из этой библиотеки,
только на каждую функции компилятор ругается undefined reference to...

```
#include <GL\glut.h>

void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(240, 240);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 740);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Как мне решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: кроме файла glut.h нужен еще файл glut32.lib, который нужно положить в папку MinGW/lib

Comment: Сделал, но ошибка осталась,DLL файлы в windows/system добавил

Comment: А вы вообще как opengl ставили?

Comment: @alexlz, инклудники и либы OpenGL идут в пакете MinGW. glut отсутствует видимо потому что исходники закрыты.

Comment: в инклудах была папка GL но глута там не было я его ставил туда сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут по идее решение проблемы: [HOWTO Use Mark J. Kilgard's OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) with MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_Mark_J_Kilgards_OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit_GLUT_with_MinGW)

Сам пока не проверял, при первой возможности попробую.

**UPD.** Перед `#include <GL\glut.h>` нужно добавить `#include <windows.h>` или две строки:

```
#define _STDCALL_SUPPORTED
#define _M_IX86
```

glut32.lib кладем в папку с исходником. Компилируем из командной строки:

```
gcc имя_экзешника.exe имя_исходника.c glut32.lib -lopengl32
```

Более полный пример командной строки есть здесь: [MinGW - OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/MinGW)

Answer (score 1):

Ругаться должен не компилятор, а компоновщик. Это значит, что нужно подключить glut32.lib. Не знаю, как это делается в MinGW, так как всегда использовал Visual Studio. Если ты компилируешь через командную строку, то надо передать в неё параметр с "glut32.lib", если через IDE, то надо искать в настройках компоновщика и добавить туда glut32.lib.